# @web alias in multisite setup with different domains

Tags: multi-site, multi-domain, alias

We're working a multisite project where the individual sites have different domains. We want to have a simple setup where both sites share an asset folder (`web/cms-assets`). So far, we're looking at the approach [detailed here](https://nystudio107.com/blog/multi-environment-configuration-for-craft-cms-3#multi-site-multi-environment-in-craft-cms):

```
# .env
SITE_ONE_URL=https://site-one.com/
SITE_TWO_URL=https://site-two.com/
```

```php
// config/general.php
'aliases' => [
    '@siteOneUrl' => getenv('SITE_ONE_URL'),
    '@siteTwoUrl' => getenv('SITE_TWO_URL'),
],
```

Then use those aliases for the `baseUrl` setting for the two sites. Now the problem is that now the `@web` alias is not defined, so Craft infers it from the request. The docs are pretty clear that this is not recommmended. So we would need a way to define the `@web` alias based on the current site's URL. One approach would be to check the current URL and set the alias to the matching domain based on that in `config/general.php` – but that feels wrong, and it doesn't work for console requests. Another problem are asset URLs – currently, the asset volume's base URL is set to `@web/cms-assets/`. We'd like for this to resolve to an absolute URL with the URL of the current site, but this means settings the `@web` alias based on the current URL again.

Is there a way to set the `@web` alias based on the current site's `baseUrl`? Or are we approaching this in the wrong way? What would be the standard/recommended way to approach this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, what's wrong with setting `@web` to an empty string in general.php? I'm not using it for anything. Asset paths can start with `@siteOneUrl`/`@siteTwoUrl` if you want absolute URLs, but often I just use a symlink instead so that I can use site-root relative paths.

Comment: @JamesSmith Currently we have `@web` set to `/`, so everything using it will use absolute paths relative to the current URL. This should work for the asset URLs at least. IIRC some console commands require an URL for the `@web` though, or am I misremembering something?

Comment: I have a note to myself in a multi site project that asset (re)indexing via the console requires a full base path (the filesystem path) to work properly, but not necessarily a full URL. So I also abstracted the base path to env vars.

Comment: @JamesSmith Thanks for the insights, I'll test that out next week!